# free(temp) pointer frees head pointer in linked list-How to retain pointer to origin of list

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have a question, if I wish to delete a node from linked list and I do this :
Assume: Head points to first node.

```
   deleteFirstNode(struct node * head)
  {
   struct node* temp=head;//this line
   temp->next=head->next->next;
   temp->data=head->next->data;
   free(head);
   head=temp;
  }
```

1) will this delete first node?

2) If so, when I free head , will it not free temp pointer too? because both temp and head point to same location in this line (see comment in "this line" in code). 
If both above are true, how will I retain retain pointer to beginning of the list. ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete the node that `head` points to; you have several problems:

1) you pass in a copy of the `head` pointer - the function is unable to change the original `head` pointer the function was called with, so the last line of the function, `head=temp` does nothing really. When the function returns whatever you had pointing to the first node on the list will now be pointing to freed memory. In effect, you have lost the list.

2) when you're grabbing `head->next->data` you're not getting the data item you want because `head->next` has been overwritten.

3) `free(head)` will also free `temp` since it points to the same thing as `head`.  `temp` is kind of pointless.

Some notes in the code:

```
deleteFirstNode(struct node * head)
{
    struct node* temp=head;

    temp->next=head->next->next;  // note: this overwrites head->next
    temp->data=head->next->data;  //       so this gets what used to be
                                  //         head->next->next->data

    free(head);     // this frees `temp` (which is an alias for `head`)
                    //      - so whats the point of `temp`?

    head=temp;      // this is pointless in more ways than one
}
```

So here's a proposed (untested) alternate version of `deleteFirstNode()`:

```
deleteFirstNode(struct node ** head)
{
    struct node* temp = *head;      // temp points to the node we want to free
    struct node* next = temp->next; // next points to what will be the new
                                    //  first node

    free(temp);
    *head=next;
}
```

You will have to call the function by passing in a pointer to the head pointer:

```
struct node* head_pointer;

// ...

deleteFirstNode(&head_pointer);
```

Another thing to consider:

- if your head pointer is `NULL`, `deleteFirstNode()` will not work. You should make it handle that case.

Comment: that was really helpful, can you please evaluate my final solution below. Thank you. Will it work?

Answer (score 4):

i would pass a double pointer and do something on these lines

```
deleteFirstNode(struct node ** head) {
  struct node* temp= *head;
  *head = temp->next;
  free(temp);
}
```

Comment: Hello Keety, I am not sure of pointer to pointer, can you please evaluate my answer below, I thank you for support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have two pointers pointing to the same address.
So deallocating memory by calling `free()` on either of them will free the pointed memory.

**EDIT:**
For understanding Link lists always draw them on piece of paper.

```
-------------      ------------       ----------- 
|           |      |          |       |         |
|   head    |----->|  first   |------>| second  | 
|           |      |          |       |         |
-------------      ------------       -----------
```

Steps you need to do are:

Isolate `first`.
Make `head` point to `Second`.
free `first`.

```
temp = head->next; //temp now points to first
head = temp->next; //head now points to second
free(temp);
```

Comment: @Ranjan: The intent of the `deleteFirstNode()` as the name suggests is to delete the first node. i.e: The node pointed by the `head`. Ideally, to do this, You will have to make `head` point to the node which is after the first node, and then delete first node.The idea is to have the link list intact and the node to be removed must first be isolated from the list and then freeing it.

Comment: Can you please evaluate my answer below. Thank you for your effort. It helped .

Answer (score 1):

> will this delete first node?

Yes.

> If so, when I free head , will it not free temp pointer too? because both temp and head point to same location in this line (see
>   comment in "this line" in code).

Yes, it will free the memory pointed by `temp` too as both `head` and `temp` are pointing to same memory. Pointer `head` will be pointing to an invalid memory location after this method is executed.

Comment: Hello Asha, then how can I still retain reference to starting node of the list.

Comment: @Ranjan: for example, you return a pointer to the head->next before you delete it, that will point to the "new head" after the deletion.

Comment: @vsz, if I have a return statement, then how will it execute free statement?

Comment: *Pointer head will be pointing to an invalid memory location* it points to a valid memory location just that it does not belong to you and hence you cannot assume the contents of that address are valid.

Comment: @Ranjan: you will return only at the end, after you called `free()`. You actually have to return your `temp` variable, because this is your new head. You'll need to set `temp = head->next;` after that, you free the head, after that you return the temp.

Comment: @vsz, really appreciate your answer. can you evaluate my answer below , in answers section. Please? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From your suggestions above here is my final code to delete first node and return pointer to head node (which will be second node in list).

```
 struct node* freeFirstNode(struct node* head)
{
 struct node* temp;
 temp=head//edited after expert's comment
 temp->next=head->next;//please confirm if this is valid and not Bad pointer.
 temp->data=head->data;
 free(head);//how will I fix this? it will free temp too.
 return(temp);
}
```

Comment: `temp` points to nothing in particular (it's never initialized), so `temp->next` and `temp->data` are invalid expressions, and `return(temp)` will return garbage if you ever get that far.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, thank you , can you please fix my final code, that is all I have in my mind.

Comment: You're trying to do too much - just set `temp = head->next`.  Now `temp` points to the 'future' head node, and you can `free(head)` then return `temp`.  The caller of the function will need to take care that they replace their idea of the list head with the returned value. I'm not a great fan of this particular idiom (http://stackoverflow.com/a/257264/12711), but at least it *can* work.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, finally.. ! you gave me the Answer, I learned something today, temp=head->next is fix for temp=head. Great thank you.

Comment: No, in the current form (temp = head;) it's not good. If you want to return the new head (which was head->next), you should use temp=head->next;  However, it would be better if you tried to understand the inner workings of your list, for example, just draw the elements and draw arrows where the `next` is pointing. An alternative would be to use an "empty-headed list", where the head itself does not carry information, and the first element comes after the head. Look at the answer by **Als** for an example.